# Element.getElementByTag("mytag") sometimes returns empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, find, ckeditor, nodes

CKeditor Element1's outer html as below:

```
<element1 id="s1">
<mytag>Test1</mytag>
<span> </span>
Some text
<mytag>Test</mytag>
<span> </span>
<mytag>Test3</mytag>
some text
<span> </span>
</element>

var element1=EditorIns.document.getById("s1");
EditorIns.focus();
var mt=element1.getElementsByTag("mytag");
alert(mt.count());
```

Normally it's working fine, but sometimes `mt.count()` is 0.

I also tried with jQuery like this:

```
$(element1.$).find("mytag").length;
```

It also has the same problem. Please help me out from this issue

Comment: Have you checked in console whether `element1` is not undefined? What do you mean by "sometimes"? Maybe jsFiddle?

Comment: Try to use jquery wrapper selector or similar, it's always safer

Answer (score 1):

```
Write the code in a function And call this function same as following :-

<script type="text/javascript">
function testElement(){
var element1=EditorIns.document.getById("s1");
EditorIns.focus();
var mt=element1.getElementsByTag("mytag");
alert(mt.count());
}


window.onload=testElement;

</script>

The element is loading after complete the page load and window.onload will call when all the elements completely loaded on the page.
```

Answer (score 0):

or

```
$(element1).find("mytag").length;
```

if `element1` is a regular html element

Comment: element1 is Ckeditor node so we can use as html element like element1.$